# IIS button does not exist for ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2022

I am beginner for .NET and MVC technologies. When I create a project by selecting ASP.NET Core Web App option, I don't get same packages as tutorial videos. Also there is no IIS button for running the program. I think some installation are missing in my case.

Here are my steps:

1. [first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTeZf.png)
2. [second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3r6P.png)
3. [third step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQQY9.png)
4. [fourth step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYvne.png)

I get these packages with no IIS button when I create a project.

[image: fifth step]

This is what I supposed to have when I create a project:

[image: sixth step]

Comment: The start button is on the main toolbar, not the solution

Comment: Do you mean there is no IIS Express button in your visual studio?[Like this](https://imgur.com/JyNYYMd.png)

Comment: @YurongDai yes and I cannot run the program. When I enter in solution file, I cannot display any file under it. There is written "Attach" on green button

Comment: You may need to try recreating the solution or reinstalling Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't open the solution, that's why it's unable to detect startup item. You have the project folder open, but you should open `FirstWebApp.sln` file.

Comment: But I cannot display any file under the solution when i open it. Also there is written "Attach" on the green triangle button and cannot run the program

Answer (score 0):

When you open the solution, you should see a green arrow at the top bar, possibly like this:

[image: screenshot of launch button in VS 2022 toolbar, underlined in red]

Based on the comments under the question, yours may say "Attach" instead of "http". To run it via IIS Express, click the down arrow to the right of the solid red "play" triangle button:

[image: Launch menu displaying the IIS Express option along with other options]

Select IIS Express from that list and then you will be able to launch.

If you don't see those options, then chances are you have opened the .csproj file instead of the .sln file. A project file is just a container for one or more solutions; it cannot be "run", itself.

Comment: I think you may have that backward: A solution contains one or more projects, projects don't contain solutions.